# Writing an original encryption algorithm

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design

Firstly, I'd just like to clarify, I am less than a beginner when it comes to cryptography. Please bear with me. I'm sure its flawed I just don't know how.  I was bored one day, and decided to come up with my own cryptographic algorithm. I succeeded, but I am clueless on how to write a mathematical statement to define it, and I don't know how computationally intensive it will be. I am writing a paper on it and will post it online.. because well, life is short and I would love if someone out there is willing to help. So in the simplest case, lets say you have a 3x3 grid, and you want to encode the message "hello".
You write down hello in the grid like shown in the image below. You store the coordinates of where each character is, for example, "o" is located on 2,2. [image]

then, you are allowed to "move" the letters around anywhere by one square on the grid(as long as another letter isn't occupying it) and every time the letter moves one square, it either becomes the letter succeeding it in the alphabet, or the letter preceding it(there is a 50% chance for either to happen)
You are allowed to move the letters around any number of times you wish as long as you adhere to the "rules" stated above. An example of this would be[image]

Thats pretty much the idea of it. The point is that it will be incredibly difficult to get the original message in any reasonable amount of time.

Again, I sincerely apologise if my idea was explained poorly, but here is a summary

Algorithm
Step 1: input letters into grid
Step 2: Shift letters as many times as you want and note down new coordinates
Step 3: output scrambled message

Why is this bad?
How can I make it better?
How can I define it better?

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, reviewing novel cryptographic algorithms is not something we do here.

Comment: AES-GCM cipher performs outstandingly on modern computer systems and provide a rich set of useful. So why bother creating a "limited" cipher when there's more important things to focus on such as human rights of African American, Latinos, and Muslims in USA?

Comment: @DannyNiu Well, presumably OP wants to learn more about cryptography. Why bother writing comments on a website when there are more important things to focus on like human rights? :P

Answer (score 3):

Bug 1: You're not substituting the letters, frequency analysis breaks it horribly.

Bug 2: You're noting down the coordinates, it's not clear whether it's supposed to be used as the key or ciphertext.

Bug 3: Your scheme has no key, which is a violation of Kerckhoffs's principle.

That's it if you want to learn some basics about cryptography. There's plenty of good posts here if you want to learn more, and I recommend you search for these tags for intro:

classical-cipher, block-cipher, stream-cipher, authenticated-encryption, message-authentication-code,